# Question from Putnam '89: Primes of the form $101\ldots01$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, contest-math, proof-verification

I'm not a math major, but would like to compete in the Putnam.  As suggested in other questions here, I'm working some old contest problems.  I'd like some input on this attempted proof--general input is gladly welcomed, but I do have some specific questions (see bottom of post.)

> **Prompt:**
>
> How many primes among the positive integers, written as usual in the base 10, are such that their digits are alternating 1's and 0's, beginning and ending with 1?
>
> **Source:** http://www.math.ksu.edu//events/ksucomp/putnam/examquestions.htm

**Answer:** There is only one such prime, namely, $101$.

**Proof:**

Consider the numbers of the form $101\ldots01$.  Let $a_n$ be the number of this form with $n$ ones in its base-10 representation.  That is:
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^{2k} \tag{1}$$
It follows:
$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(10^2\right)^k \\
&= \frac{\left(10^2\right)^n-1}{10^2-1} \\
&= \frac{(10^n)^2-1}{99} \\
&= \frac{(10^n-1)(10^n+1)}{9\cdot 11}
\end{align}$$

We now note that $10^n-1=9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k$.  Thus:

$$a_n = \frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right)(10^n+1)}{11} \tag{2}$$

Let $b_n$ be the numerator in $(2)$; that is:
$$b_n = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right)(10^n+1)$$

From formula $(1)$, we can see that $a_n$ is the sum of integers, thus, $a_n$ is clearly an integer.  For $a_n$ to be a prime, $b_n$ must satisfy the following: 
$$b_n = 11\cdot p\text{, where $p$ is prime.}$$

Therefore, one of either $\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right)$ or $(10^n+1)$ must be $11$, and the other is prime.  For $n=1$, we see:
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right) = 1;\qquad(10^n+1)=11$$
For $n=2$, we see:
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right) = 11;\qquad(10^n+1)=101$$
As both terms are monotonically increasing, these two are the only ways to have either one equal to $11$.  Of these two, only one pair contains a prime (namely, $101$).

---

My questions:

First and foremost, I want to know if my proof is valid/on the right track. `:)`  After that, I'd like to know if I'm covering the proof in enough detail.  Specifically:

1. I assert that $10^n-1=9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k$.  Do I need to prove this, or is it obvious enough?  (Subtracting $1$ from a power of $10$ leaves a number with as many $9$s as there are $0$'s in the power of $10$.)
2. Do I need to show further why $b_n$ must be $11$ times a prime?  Or is it clear that all other cases yield composite $a_n$?
3. Is my reasoning that there are only these two solutions (i.e. monotonically increasing terms) legitimate?

And, finally, is there some well-known theorem that I have totally overlooked that would make solving this problem easy?

Comment: If I was grading it, I would give you full credit.

Comment: It's valid. After using the formula for a geometric sum, you need not worry about dividing $10^n-1$ by $10-1$. Very good job.

Comment: not a mathematician, but that was a pleasure to read.  just thanks for posting it.

Comment: Just to nitpick for Putnam-level grading: "Therefore, one of either ... or $10n+1$ must be $11$, and the other is prime." This is not strictly true. People often neglect that a factorization could involve $1$, so that one of these factors could be $1$ and the other could be $11p$. This is an easy situation to address, since it would force $n$ to be $1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks--I can't believe I overlooked that. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually cut your proof short a fair bit earlier — once you have $a_n=(10^n+1)(10^n-1)/99$, you can note that for $n\gt 2$, both of these factors are larger than $2\times 99$ and so there must be a factorization of $a_n$ into two numbers each larger than $2$.

More formally, you can split into the case of even $n$ and odd $n$; for even $n$ then $99|10^n-1$ so you have $a_n=(10^n+1)\times \left((10^n-1)/99\right)$ with each factor $\gt 1$, while for odd $n$ $11| 10^n+1$ and $9|10^n-1$ so $a_n=\left((10^n+1)/11\right)\times\left((10^n-1)/9\right)$ with each factor $\gt 1$.  (These divisibility properties are immediate from $10\equiv 1\pmod 9$ and $10\equiv -1\pmod{11}$).  This also explains why the proof breaks down at $n=2$; there, you still have $a_n=(10^n+1)\times\left((10^n-1)/99\right)$, but it's no longer the case that the right factor is $\gt 1$.

Comment: (Also, thank you for the flashback - this was one of the Putnams I took back in college, the one I did particularly well on, and it's a joy to see this question again!)

Comment: Just wanted to see if I got the idea right -- if $n > 2$ then theres a factorized quotient remaining after dividing the numerator by $99$ and that's why for $n>2$ it's composite?

Comment: @Airdish Sort of, though you don't _explicitly_ know the factors without doing the odd/even analysis - what you can say is that $a=mn / 99$ with $m$ and $n$ both greater than 99, and so you know there's _some_ factorization $a=ij$ with $i,j\gt 1$.

Comment: Alright, thanks :) This problem came in my textbook and I had no idea how to solve it, so I'm really glad I came across this post.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks good to me. Here's an alternative proof, which is not necessarily better but was the first thing that came to my mind:

Let $a_n$ be as in your proof. It is easy to see that if $m\mid n$ then $a_m\mid a_n$ (just consider the process of long division). By inspection, I found that if $n$ is odd then
$$a_n=\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 10^k\right)\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}9\cdot 10^{2k}\right).$$
Thus $a_n$ can only be prime when $n$ is an even prime, i.e. $n=2$.